# Missing defaults dictionary to restore state for: PKPaletteNamedDefaults

Tags: swift, pencilkit

> [ToolPicker] Missing defaults dictionary to restore state for: PKPaletteNamedDefaults

warning is outputted on my screen.

I am looking to resolve this error and have found that if I don't make the following call, I do not get an error.  What am I doing wrong when setting up the `PKToolPicker`?

```
struct CanvasView {

    @Binding var canvasData: Data
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    let onSaved: (Data) -> Void

    @State var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
    @State var canvasView = PKCanvasView()

}

private extension CanvasView {

    func showToolPicker() {
        toolPicker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
        if isFirstResponder { canvasView.becomeFirstResponder() }
    }

}
```

If I comment out the above if statement and call `showToolPicker()`, there isn't a warning.  I think I'm doing something wrong when setting initial values but not sure what and can't seem to find much info about `PKPaletteNamedDefaults`.